# Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net-2010

I want to compare an exam grade to the content of a listbox . 
e.g

```
textbox.text = "ABCDABCDAB"
```

and the listbox contains `(Jean,ABCDABCDAB, John,ABCCBBCCAB,  Kirou,BBCDABCDAB)`.

How do I write the program to read the textbox content and compare it to the listbox content. Hope I am clear enough. Can anybody help please? in Visual Basic 2010

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how to write it in VB but I'm sure you'll be clever enough to translate it from C#

```
if( listBox1.Items.Contains(textbox.Text) )
   // hurray!
else
   // :( no such item
```

Answer (score -1):

In VB.NET you have to write it like this:

```
If ListBox1.Items.Contains(TextBox1.Text) = True Then  Msgbox("Item exists")
```

I hope this is going to help you

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
if (ListBox1.Items.Contains(TextBox1.Text))
{
    MsgBox.Show("Yay! Item exists.");
}
else
{
    MsgBox.Show("Oops! No such item exists.");
}
```